# how to control multiple tags not neccessary that to repeat again

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

here i m target a data with table of CTD_CTD_PKG_ID in my xslt but some tags were having data pretty same that type of tags we have to control not to repeat once more

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <NewDataSet>
 <Table>
 <RECORD_TYPE_CODE>CTD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
 <MSG_TYPE_CODE>O102</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
 <CTD_SEQ_NUM>089938</CTD_SEQ_NUM>    
 <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>345</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
 <CTD_LANG_ID>E</CTD_LANG_ID>
 </Table>
 <Table>
 <RECORD_TYPE_CODE>ITD</RECORD_TYPE_CODE>
 <MSG_TYPE_CODE>O103</MSG_TYPE_CODE>
 <CTD_SEQ_NUM>089939</CTD_SEQ_NUM>    
 <CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>345</CTD_CTD_PKG_ID>
 <CTD_LANG_ID>E</CTD_LANG_ID>
 </Table>   
 </NewDataSet>
```

i have written my xslt below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="PackageId"  />
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345']"/>     
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345']">

<xsl:value-of select= "concat(':25:',./CTD_LANG_ID)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    <xsl:if test ="./RECORD_TYPE_CODE"  >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':20:',./RECORD_TYPE_CODE)" />,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./MSG_TYPE_CODE" >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':21:',./MSG_TYPE_CODE)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test ="./CTD_SEQ_NUM" >
        <xsl:if test=" position() &gt; 1"></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select= "concat(':22:',./CTD_SEQ_NUM)"/>,<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:if>       

</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

current output for this above xslt

:25:E,:25:E,

Expected output=
**:25:E,**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using such specific IDs, a simple way to do this would be to simply select the first TABLE with the matching ID using the position() function, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345'][position()=1]"/>
```

Note that, you can actually simplify the template match by just matching on Table if required. Here is the whole XSLT in this case

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="PackageId"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID ='345'][position()=1]"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Table">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(':25:',./CTD_LANG_ID)"/>,
      <xsl:text/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your input XML, the result is as follows:

```
:25:E,
```

Comment: but i am using some other tags in that template just please check i have edited that template if i use this it may cause effect

Comment: @pravz Now you have amended your XSLT, is your expected output still the same in this case?